# Dynamically calculate the percentage utilisation in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the below query that produces the following output. I am trying to add a column to the query called percentage utilisation that is calculated by the formula (count/total count). For example, percentage utilisation for device D1 would be 220/(220+322) * 100 and for device D2 would be 322/(220+322) * 100. If the Id has only one row, then utilisation should be 100%. (Eg: third row) I was wondering whether there is a way to achieve this in Google big query.

```
SELECT Id,Device,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([db.table1],TIMESTAMP('2016-08-01'),TIMESTAMP('2016-08-10'))
WHERE Id = 331
GROUP BY Id,Device
ORDER BY Id
```

Output:

```
Row  Id  Device  Count   
 1  331   D1    220  
 2  331   D2    322  
 3  332   D4    550
```

Expected output:

```
Row  Id  Device  Count   Percentage utilisation
 1  331   D1    220         40
 2  331   D2    322         60
 3  332   D4    550         100
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  Id, Device, COUNT(*) AS Count, 
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(Count) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS Utilisation
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([db.table1],TIMESTAMP('2016-08-01'),TIMESTAMP('2016-08-10'))
GROUP BY Id, Device
ORDER BY Id
```